# Searching an array for 2 word string

Tags: arrays, string, search, inventory

In a game I'm making, the player is able to purchase items from a store and then they may use them in the game. I have the items in an array and to check to see if the user has the item, I want to search the inventory.

```
private static void fuelCar() {
    for (String str : satchel){
        superGarbage = str.contains("Super Garbage");
        if(superGarbage){
            fueled =  true;
            System.out.println("You put fuel in the car.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You don't have any fuel, you need super garbage!");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it works because when I searched the inventory for a map, it would work, my issue though is that the specific item I need to search for is a two word string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Despite the fact that all the String comparaisons will slow you down: Where exactly is the problem? I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to consider using id's and names for the objects and referencing those on a map, so anytime you want to check something in the software, you rather check for the id's and if it's necessary to show something to the user then find the information on the map.

Good luck!